# Angular 9 - prevent component destruction

Tags: angular9

Can we prevent component destruction in a situation like this. Let's say the component is shown using *ngif="condition". When it's true the component is on the screen, but when it's not the component is removed from the screen and its ngOnDestroy is fired.

Is there any way to work around that problem?

Thanks

Comment: use [hidden]="!someCondition" but most of the time this is an antipattern because you are somehow trying to preserve state where you shouldn't

Comment: While I will try your suggestion can you explain why it's an anti-pattern? Angular docs have ngif clearly explained as a good approach.

Comment: Also seems like hidden gets evaluate only once no data binding would work. That's why ngif is working better with real stuff when data is pulled from the server.

Comment: ngIf is a good approach but the component will be destroyed. Your question was how to prevent destruction. Or, well implicitly you labeled the destruction as a problem. Data binding is another subject, and not directly related to component destruction. You are probably passing variables and without them being observables or implementing the onChanges interface changes will not be detected.